# How to use javascript to new java inner class in Rhino engine?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, kettle

Here I write some js code in **kettle** Modified Java Script Value step (which use **Rhino engine**), to use java API. Actually, all the code works well. For example:

```
var fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(filePath); //new file object
```

But if I want to use the inner class, how could I new inner class in **js** environment? Here is the demo:

```
//java
public class Out{
   public static class In {
       public String test = "Hello";
   }
}
//use inner class
Out.In in = new Out.In();
System.out.print(in.test); // successful!!


//js
var out = new Out();    // successful
var in = new Out.In();  // error here.
```

error message

```
org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@55516dbb is not a function, it is undefined
```

We can find that, javascript compiler **view In() as a function of class Out**, but  actually In() is the inner class of Out.

From the Internet, I find that Nashorn, a newer javascript engine, supports scripts access java inner access, which grammar is that

```
var Float = Java.type("java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float"); // using $ to indicate inner class
```

My question is that, how can I new a inner class from Rhino??? There must be several methods somewhere.

Any help is greatly needed!!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with kettle, but according to the error message, Rhino JavaScript engine is used there. I guess, the problem is not with inner classes, but with absence of `Packages.` prefix. By default only `java.` top-level package is imported to Rhino JavaScript context. Other classes are accessible using `Packages.` prefix. If your `Out` class is located in the default package, try to use

```
var in = new Packages.Out.In();
```

If not, prepend it with the full package name. For example, if your Java code appears in `com.example` package, use

```
var in = new Packages.com.example.Out.In();
```

For more information see [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java#Accessing_Java_Packages_and_Classes) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :D. But I guess the problem is not related to the prefix. Because I have successfully create the object of Out class. `var out = new org.pentaho.di.trans.Out(); //success`  and creating inner class is failed. `var in = new out.In(); //error`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `Out` class into any package, e.g. `org.Out`.
Then use it from `JavaScript` like this `new org.Out.In().test;`

You are trying to do smth equivalent to Java 

`Out o = new Out(); 
new o.In(); // compilation error here`

And this also will not work in Java. So I think it is not a Rhino issue at all

Also you can try to write

`var field = new org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mongodboutput.MongoDbOutputMeta.MongoField();`

Comment: Sorry for my syntax error in the first comment. And I tried `var field = new Packages.org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta(sourcePath).findStep("MongoDB Output").getStepMetaInterface().MongoField();` The error message is the same, `Cannot find function MongoField in object org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mongodboutput.MongoDbOutputMeta@3fb075f3. `

Comment: I reedit your answer because I am trying to new inner class In in this way `var in = new Out.In(); // here is the class name Out, not the object out.` As a result this works in Java.

Comment: Maybe this situation is not caused by Rhino, but kettle. I shall install Rhino shell to check.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
var out = new Out();  
var in = new Out.In(out);
```

Inner class constructor requires outer class instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled about this when examining a very similar problem in Eclipse BIRT.

We are using the same Java construct, a public outer class and a public static inner class.
We are trying to create an instance of the inner class from Javascript inside BIRT (which uses the Rhino engine).

This fails with Java 6, but it works with Java 8, so obviously this is related to some change in Rhino between Java 6 and 8.